# Solubility of p-nitrophenol in various substances?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solubility

So I had an organic chemistry lab where we had to dissolve p-nitrophenol in water, dilute $\ce{NaHCO3}$, dilute $\ce{NaOH}$, and dilute $\ce{HCl}$ to test for solubility.

The p-nitrophenol dissolved in everything but water. I just want to make sure if these results are theoretically correct. From what I understand, the nitrophenol should have also dissolved in water because its a polar substance and it shouldn't have dissolved in $\ce{HCl}$ because I think the Hydrogen in the phenol is itself acidic due to electron withdrawing effects of the benzene.

Can someone please explain what should happen?

Answer (score 3):

[*p*-Nitrophenol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4-Nitrophenol) is actually modestly soluble in water at neutral pH (16 g/l at 25 °C) because of its weak acidity ($p\mathrm{K_a}=7.16$ at 22 °C) and the formation of intermolecular hydrogen bonds between the phenolic OH group and water molecules. The latter would also explain why the compound dissolves in diluted $\ce{HCl_{aq}}$ despite being protonated at lower pH values. The importance of intermolecular hydrogen bonds is also demonstrated by the significantly lower solubility of the *ortho* isomer, which forms intramolecular hydrogen bonds and therefore appears to be less polar to the solvent ([source](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=18&ved=0CFMQFjAHOAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fchemistry.csudh.edu%2Ffaculty%2Fjim%2Fphenols.ppt&ei=zRTNU7q0PPT44QSEt4DYAw&usg=AFQjCNGGlPgxnL_gh7UZoFbESUub5m0DBQ&bvm=bv.71198958,d.bGE)):

[image]

In basic solutions, *p*-nitrophenol is deprotonated to *p*-nitrophenolate. The anion is stabilized by delocalization of the negative charge into the benzene ring and the electron-withdrawing nitro group (only two of the possible resonance structures are shown):

[image]